# Push Notification - set rootViewController when app is closed from background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I have implemented push notification using firebase. It works as I want to accomplish while app is on foreground also in background. But when app is closed from background and notification is open from message, I want to reset my rootViewController. So I changed it on `didReceive response:` but still while app is re-opening, it goes back to old rootViewController(which has been set on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ).

PS. Default rootViewController is a luncher animation viewController which has some animation with delay, then it will redirect to another ViewController which will be set as rootViewController

Here is the code snippet:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState

    if state == .active {
        // foreground
        // Will return current viewController which is showing into screen
        let rootVC = getCurrentViewController()
        let reviewVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ReviewViewController.className) as! ReviewViewController
        rootVC?.present(reviewVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // background
        let swVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
        window?.rootViewController = swVC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        // Will return current viewController which is showing into screen
        let rootVC = self.getCurrentViewController()
        let reviewVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ReviewViewController.className) as! ReviewViewController
        rootVC?.present(reviewVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: When Application is closed no line of code will be executed. Every time you run the app didFinishLaunchingOption method will run either you open the app from notification tray or from spring board.

Comment: But when I remove that luncher animation screen and set my default root ViewController into normal ViewController, it shows my desire ViewController while app is open from notification tray

Comment: Can you explain in simple words what you want and what issue you are facing. Try to exemplify like animationScreen and ChatScreen. Instead of using the word rootViewController.

Comment: So what issue u are facing when u tap on a notification?

Comment: By default App started from animationScreen which has some delay and  will redirect into homeScreen and set homeScreen as root. When a notification is opened from tray I want to reset my root into another viewController. But when I tap into notification it doesn't open that viewController which is set into `didReceive response:`

Comment: Can you share your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method code?

Comment: Here it is [AppDelegate Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/222aadf96b236b7cf7f62581a6329482)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165817/discussion-between-syed-qamar-abbas-and-sz-ashik).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line form your `didReceive` method.

```
let swVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
window?.rootViewController = swVC
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```